What are the scenarios where a Chrome content override will not apply?
Chrome response overrides are a super useful tool for testing, but I'm having trouble having the override apply in my real-world use case.
As a simple of example for where they do work:
Visit https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/
Open the dev tools, and in the console run:
fetch("/posts") 
fetch("/posts", {method: "POST"})


Observe the requests in the network tab.
Now right click the post request, and 'override content' - note that this is prepopulated with the response on the GET request.
Note though, if we enter our custom response, the POST will have its response overridden.
What then, are the scenarios where the POST request will not be overridden?

The question is weird. What makes you think such scenarios exist? Did you encounter one? Or what are you trying to do here? I'm assuming you ran into some caching issue, but the question could use details.

Yea, knowing a specific instance you've observed would help us help you find a specific cause, but without a specific situation, you're asking us to shoot in the dark. This site does require practical and narrow questions, and this is, currently, not particularly practical, and not narrow enough.

apologies, initially the question was 'why don't overrides work for POST requests', but then I noticed that it was working in my reproduction. Yes, in my actual work environment the override wasn't working, but then it did start working randomly, so maybe it was just some glitch.

In my case, when there is a timeout error, the Override Content option is just disabled.
